# Upload Folder/Directory via HTML and keep structure

Tags: javascript, html, upload, compression, directory

I need a way to move a complete Folder from client to server and keep its structure. Sadly, not every browser seems to support multi-upload.
So my idea was, to `zip`/`tar` the data with javascript before uploading them to my server.
Is this a possible workaround for my issue? Any Ideas?